# Invalid configuration object. webpack

Tags: webpack

npm run dev gives me this error:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'modules'. These properties are valid:
   object { mode?, amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, optimization?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, serve?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack >= v2.0.0 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           modules: …
         }
       })
     ]
```

## webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const htmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = env => {
  const no_dist = env && env.dist === "false";

  return {
    //webpack configuration
    entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/js/index.js"],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename: "js/bundle.js"
    },
    mode: "development",
    devServer: {
      inline: false,
      contentBase: "./dist"
    },
    plugins: [
      new htmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: "index.html",
        template: "./src/index.html"
      })
    ],
    modules: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
};
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "espn_project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": " project ",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --env.dist=false",
    "dev:dist": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open"
  },
  "author": "Chris Kelly",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.18.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0"
  }
}
```

## .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["/env"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says:

> configuration has an unknown property **'modules'**. These properties are valid: object { mode?, amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry?, externals?, loader?, **module?** ...

It is telling you that you have a property called `modules` that isn't valid. The correct property name is `module` (without the "s").